# Ubuntu VM display not loading correctly on iMac 5k

Tags: virtualbox, display, macosx

I'm trying to install Ubuntu (14.10 64bit) on my iMac 5k. After creating the VirtualBox VM [10GB, 2Gb mem], I load the Ubuntu ISO, and then the VM display is all over the place (see below). It seems Ubuntu is running, but the display isn't working correctly... I'm guessing is due to the iMac 5k resolution/controller. Any ideas what the problem might be?

Screenshot of display output: [image]

The configuration of the VM is as follows: [image]

Comment: In theory, Ubuntu does not see the iMac controller at all; it sees the VirtualBox's virtual controller.  It should see the same video controller as it would on any other system.  So, there must be a problem with VirtualBox on your system.  Their forums might be a better source of help.  By the way, is this the CD (iso file) booting, or the disk after installation?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found a workaround to this issue:

Once  that screen appears, hold the Host+F1 key (it should show the Ubuntu console), and then then the Host+F7 combination (goes back to the Ubuntu installation window). Before you do that just make sure you have the Function keys set to act as normal function keys on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem - I believe this is Ubuntu problem. I installed Windows 7 without problems.  I also installed different distro of Linux (mint) but then it is very slow. Playing a bit I managed to install Ubuntu 14.10 - I believe that there is driver problem in Ubuntu (or in general Linux) not working properly with AMD driver in Yosemite.